# "award something out" Is it idiomatic?

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

I find the preposition **out** in [this sentence](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+voice+to) strange.

> When we left the office, Sally gave voice to her fear that promotions are unfairly awarded **out** in our department.

Most Google search results are false positives as "award out of the blue". Is it an idiomatic phrase?

Comment: I also find it strange. The meaning is clear, but the phrase is not one I have ever heard, as far as I can recall. Note that the phrasal verb _give out_ exists, but not _award out_ in my experience.

Comment: If I were editing it, I would simply remove *out*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When we left the office, Sally gave voice to her fear that promotions are unfairly awarded **out** in our department.

Here **out** is an adverb specifying the directional transfer of promotions. The choice to use **out** in this manner seems clumsy to me. I think the meaning would be clearer without it, as the meaning does not change.

For similar use of **out**, consider:

> They handed out pamphlets at the train station.
>
> Gifts will be given out as guests leave the party.